# Orchestration for Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, orchestration

I am creating a Spring Boot service which intern calls multiple other services. Some can be called in parallel, while others are blocking calls which needs to be sequential.
Essentially it creates a request DAG.

I can do all this manually, but is there an existing orchestration layer/library I can use which will help me simplify these ? Is there a way I can say

```
call_service_1 -> (use data from service 1 and call_service_2)
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
               -> (use data from service 1 and call_service_3) -> (use data from service 3 and call_service_4) -> (use data from service 4 and service 1 to call_service_5)
```

Is there something out there which will help me stitch this neatly ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is Spring Cloud Data Flow the answer?  https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-dataflow

Comment: Or perhaps Netflix Conductor: https://netflixtechblog.com/netflix-conductor-a-microservices-orchestrator-2e8d4771bf40

Comment: It comes down to your specific needs. Apache Camel with its reach set of already implemented Enterprise Integration Patterns can be a good way to go. https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/eips/enterprise-integration-patterns.html

Also in my view too much orchestration in a single service increases the complexity and makes changes difficult and more expensive to test. If possible I will combine orchestration with choreography and have the functionality split across  multiple services